# Display subtitle and custom axis's names for 3d mesh chart with plotly.js

Tags: javascript, plotly.js

Is it possible to display subtitle for 3D mesh chart with plotly.js. Also struggling about custom names for axis.

I'm following examples from original website.

https://codepen.io/plotly/pen/oLNPXG

```
var data=[  {   opacity:0.8,    color:'rgb(300,100,200)',
        type: 'mesh3d',
        showlegend: true,
        x: a,
        y: b,
        z: c
    } ];
```

Comment: This link might be useful - https://plot.ly/javascript/text-and-annotations/#3d-annotations

Comment: Still don't know how to turn on legend in 3D chart. Is it not allowed?